# Once a Content provider is updated, how can I inform all listeners there was an update?

Tags: android

Hi basically I have a table, this table is getting information from a content provider I wrote.  If I update a content provider how can I force an update on the UI whenever the data is changed in the content provider?

FOr example:
If a list is showing
A
B

and I add C to the content provider

how can I get the UI to show
A
B
C
as soon as it updates?  Or does it automatically broadcast any changes for me?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/observing-content.html) post, which talks about content observers. I would say listen for changes, when one occurs update your list. Since your application is the one doing the inserting (although others may as well), you could just update your list after inserting a record.

Comment: When you control the `ContentProvider`, `ContentObserver.notifyChange()` and `Cursor.setNotificationUri()` is definitely the way to go. It's thread-safe, clean and integrates nicely with `CursorAdapter` (i.e. zero-effort).