# Notifying about change inside a ContentProvider: is it thread safe in Loaders perspective?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-contentprovider, android-loader

I have a ContentProvider backed up by SQLiteDatabase and it has a rather common implementation, i.e:

```
class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public void update(...) {
        // write stuff to DB
        //...
        // done writing stuff

        getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
    }
}
```

I also use a `CursorLoader` to perform query and display its results in adapter/listview.

No thread synchronization is done in my ContentProvider.

It is not very clear for me what happens in the following case:

1. I start some custom non-ui thread and call `update()` to change some values in DB inside this thread.
2. This `update()` causes `notifyChange(...)` to be called
3. My `CursorLoader` picks up this change and updates adapter, which updates a `ListView`

Is the above scenario OK from a thread-safety perspective? I mean, look, values are written using one thread (non-ui), then same thread notifies about changes and lastly changes are picked up by `CursorLoader` which I suspect uses some *other* background thread to load its data.

Do I need to do some manual thread synchronization or will it just work? (Android may already be smart about all this stuff)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481978/how-to-create-a-thread-safe-contentprovider?rq=1 Also read the Vogella 5.4. Security and ContentProvider at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Yes, I've read all this. I'm mainly interested, will notifyChange() cause some synchronization to happen before loader picks it up. If it does, then I do not have to worry. If it doesn't, then I need to be careful :)

Comment: In this comment it is noted that notifyChange is thread-safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478181/once-a-content-provider-is-updated-how-can-i-inform-all-listeners-there-was-an#comment9050532_7478223. But SDK docs do not mention it...